# Downloaded asset bundle prefabs script icons missing in inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, assetbundle

I have built an AR app with vuforia in Unity. I discovered that the script icons in the inspector of a cloned prefab are missing, whereas the script icons of a drag-and-drop prefab are appearing normally. The model appears normally when the marker is tracked in the drag-and-drop prefab but not in the cloned prefabs. I am not sure is there anything happened to the downloaded cloned prefab?

[Downloaded Asset Bundle prefabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX0Jx.jpg)

[Drag-and-drop prefabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHymD.jpg)

[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a33j2.png)

[AssetManager.cs related to the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKrMi.png)

[resumeScene2.cs related to the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFMkX.png)

I tried to rebuild the asset bundle but seems like the script icons were still missing in downloaded prefabs. I think the first four errors have nothing to do with the assetBundle, they are only to checking status of QR scanning whether unlocked or locked.

Comment: could you show/tell us what those 12 errors in the console are?

Comment: I have edited the post by adding the errors into the post.